# display recordcount

Tags: vbscript, adodb

I have the following, but it is not putting the count of records from the query in the `MsgBox`.  Only the RR and the TT.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim recordCount2

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=servername\logon;Initial Catalog=database_name"
con.Open
strQry = "SELECT * FROM smd..table_name (nolock) WHERE CAST(LastRunDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND TableNameKey in ('value1', 'value2')"
Set data = con.Open(strQry)

objRecordset.Open strQuery, adoConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

recordCount2 = objRecordset.Count
MsgBox "TT " &  recordCount2 & "RR"

objRS.Close: Set objRS = Nothing 
con.Close: Set con = Nothing
```

Comment: ***NEVER*** use global `On Error Resume Next`, particularly if you're not doing any kind of error handling. Contrary to popular belief it doesn't magically make errors go away. It just makes them impossible to debug. Also remove the line `Set data = con.Open(strQry)` (what's that supposed to do anyway?), and actually check the [connection state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

My guess is there's an error that's occurring which is being hidden by `On error resume next`, and `recordCount2 = objRecordset.Count` is not actually succeeding.  Why do you have `On error resume next` anyway?  Delete that line or comment it out, and your problem should become obvious.

Comment: Completely agree, the likely cause being the fact this line makes no sense - `objRecordset.Open strQuery, adoConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic`, what is `strQuery` and `adoConnection` both are not defined in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `On Error Resume Next` isn't a *"[magic bullet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/magic_bullet)"*. Especially like this quote from [@ansgar-wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers)

> *"Contrary to popular belief it doesn't magically make errors go away."*

`On Error Resume Next` is very useful but needs to be used in the correct context. While it is active any statement that raises an error is handled silently, the statement that raised the error is skipped and the inbuilt [`Err` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf5ze0e(v=vs.84).aspx) is populated with the error details for error trapping.

As others have suggested the first thing you should do when debugging these types of problems is comment out `On Error Resume Next` then the issues I'm about to highlight you might have found yourself.

In the example above there are a couple of lines that are likely raising errors and being skipped, these are;

```
Set data = con.Open(strQry)
```

This statement appears to want to execute the query in `strQry` but `con.Open()` is the wrong method for this, the `ADODB.Connection` is already open it doesn't need opening again. You likely meant *(but this is a pure guess)*;

```
Set data = con.Execute(strQry)
```

You don't appear to use `data` after you try running it so I would in this situation just comment it out for now.

The next is;

```
objRecordset.Open strQuery, adoConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

which tries to open the `ADO.Recordset` using `strQuery` which doesn't appear to defined and neither is `adoConnection` you likely meant *(again guess work)*;

```
objRecordset.Open strQry, con, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

If this statement raises an error and is skipped the statement

```
recordCount2 = objRecordset.Count
```

will itself error because the `objRecordset` `.State` will be set to `adStateClosed`.

After these suggestions you should have something like;

```
'On Error Resume Next
Dim recordCount2, constr

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
constr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=servername\logon;Initial Catalog=database_name"
con.Open constr
strQry = "SELECT * FROM smd..table_name (nolock) WHERE CAST(LastRunDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND TableNameKey in ('value1', 'value2')"
'Set data = con.Open(strQry)

objRecordset.Open strQry, con, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

recordCount2 = objRecordset.Count
MsgBox "TT " &  recordCount2 & "RR"

objRecordset.Close: Set objRecordset = Nothing 
con.Close: Set con = Nothing
```

Comment: hi. i tried the preceding suggestion.  but now i am getting an error SQL Server does not exist or access denied.  I made sure my server name exists and is spelled correctly.  What would cause this error? Could it be a security setting at work?

Comment: @user2811136 the fact you are getting that far is progress, you now just need to make sure that you're using the right connection string. At the moment it's expecting a [trusted connection to the SQL Server](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/trusted-connection/) which is likely not going to work in this scenario. Post a bit more information about what version of SQL Server you are running and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid writing code as much as possible by writing only those lines/statements you are absolutely sure of. If you haven't seen a bit of documentation that explains why the statement x is neccessary to solve your problem, leave x off.

Before writing code, read the docs: [RecordCount property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms676701(v=vs.85).aspx):

> ... The cursor type of the Recordset object affects whether the number
>   of records can be determined. The RecordCount property will return -1
>   for a forward-only cursor; the actual count for a static or keyset
>   cursor; and either -1 or the actual count for a dynamic cursor,
>   depending on the data source. ...

So your plan is:

1. Open a connection
2. Get a recordset
3. Access its .RecordCount

The general skeleton for a VBScript contains:

```
Option Explicit
```

It does **not** contain the evil global OERN.

The database work specific skeleton contains:

```
Dim oCn : Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oCn.Open "DSN=???"
...
oCn.Close
```

It does `not` contain distracting `Set x = Nothing` tails.

For production scripts or test code wrt connection problems, you need to write long/complicated/tailored connection strings; for experimental code wrt small specific database features/problems/surprises a (once-for-all-puzzled-together-with-GUI-support) ODBC/DSN connection is more efficient and less error-prone.

The Recordset should be .Opened to play with the Cursor Type:

```
oRs.Open "SELECT AddressId FROM Person.Address", oCn, adOpenDynamic
```

Optional Locking left off (until you have documentary or experimental evidence that Lock Type influences .RecordCount).

If you try to run

```
Option Explicit

Dim oCn : Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oCn.Open "DSN=AdvWork"
Dim oRs : Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oRs.Open "SELECT AddressId FROM Person.Address", oCn, adOpenDynamic
WScript.Echo ".RecordCount:", oRs.RecordCount
oCn.Close
```

you will be told: Variable is undefined: 'adOpenDynamic'. A bit of further (re)reading and your code will look like

```
Option Explicit
Const adOpenKeyset = 1

Dim oCn : Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oCn.Open "DSN=AdvWork"
Dim oRs : Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oRs.Open "SELECT AddressId FROM Person.Address", oCn, adOpenKeyset
WScript.Echo ".RecordCount:", oRs.RecordCount
oCn.Close
```

output:

```
cscript 39519953.vbs
.RecordCount: 19614
```

and the world is a (little bit) better place.

Comment: hi.  i have a user who has a password like testingthis01!.  But I think the ! is throwing it off.  I am getting error that says "Login failed..."

Comment: There's nothing evil about `On Error Resume Next` if used in the correct context and debugging it isn't a problem when all you have to do is comment the line out. Recommending DSN usage is all well and good but not everyone has direct access to their web server *(shared hosting, over protective network admins etc.)*, not to mention the mind field of putting the DSN in the correct place on 32 / 64 bit systems. Also encouraging people not to release object references is just silly there's nothing distracting about them the benefits outweight the inconvenience *(if you could even call it that)*

Answer (score 0):

@Brad Larson and @Ekkehard.Horner.... thanks for the guidance, i too was struggling to get the record count from a recordset using VBS and obtaining some info from the windows SYSTEMINDEX (it kept returning -1).
Setting up the `Const adOpenKeyset = 1` and then adding that term to the `[recordset.oen "SELECT....", oCn, adOpenKeyset]` line made it work!!

> you will be told: Variable is undefined: 'adOpenDynamic'. A bit of
>   further (re)reading and your code will look like
>
> ```
> Option Explicit
> Const adOpenKeyset = 1
>
> Dim oCn : Set oCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
> oCn.Open "DSN=AdvWork"
> Dim oRs : Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
> oRs.Open "SELECT AddressId FROM Person.Address", oCn, adOpenKeyset
> WScript.Echo ".RecordCount:", oRs.RecordCount
> oCn.Close
> ```
>
> output: cscript 39519953.vbs .RecordCount: 19614 and the world is a
>   (little bit) better place.